# How to change the cookie name for FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule

Tags: asp.net

I am using `FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionCookie` and I see cookies `FedAuth` and `FedAuth1`.

I'm having some issues moving hosts and different machine keys, and I don't want to ask all my users to clear their cookies.

How can I change the cookie name?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler name="NewCookieNameGoesHere" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```